# HTML5 Boilerplate with Twitter Bootstrap templates

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

I am having number of questions about this template world.I feel this is the right place for put my problems.

**Q 1.** I have installed `HTML5` Boilerplate (`H5BT`) default template for my ASP.Net MVC 3 project.So then I need to find the template for the my application.I need to have choice to do that.Are there any collection of templates for H5BT ? If it’s there plz
put a link for that.

**Q 2.** After installing default template of `H5BT` for my mvc 3 application then can I use any Bootstrap template (`BST`) with my app. ?

**Q 3.** I saw lot of buttons, scaffolding and lot of UI components exist with `BST` but how can I find such a collection for `H5BT` ? If it’s there plz put that link.

**Q 4.** This is related to the **Q 3**.That is Can I use `BST` components (buttons, etc ) with `H5BT` default template which has been installed with my mvc 3 app. ?

**Q 5.** Still I am having a chance to choice pre-build template for my app.So which should you suggest for me.Either `H5BT` or `BST` ?

Answer (score 3):

1. HTML5 Boilerplate is not about the templates, it's a clean plate on top of which you can put anything that is required.
2. Yes, you can use Bootstrap on top of Boilerplate. Check this link - Initializr which seamlessly combines the two. - http://www.initializr.com/
3. Again, I don't know and think such templates will be there. You can always use templates available for Bootstrap - http://bootswatch.com/#gallery

These will automatically answer your q4 and q5 :)

Comment: I couldn't understand the layout of http://www.initializr.com/ site ?There are 3 buttons exist.What are the functions those buttons do ? If you understand well plz let me know.

Comment: Are you sure which we can use BST templates on top of H5BP ? B'cos BST templates requires separate set of css and javascript. But H5BP's having separate set of that kind.So then how can I make things together.Any idea ?

Comment: well yes, there are three buttons. Now if you click on the Big blue button of Bootstrap, a slide down effect happens and you are shown with some customization option. That's where you can decide which all things you need like Boostrap normal or responsive, Boiler plate html template, .htaccess file etc. Let me know if this helps you understand.

Comment: Ok.I feel you're wrong here.B'cos when we consider this view-source:http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html template from BST you can see it requires all the css and js files of BST.When I am having H5BT as default template then I am having css and js related to the H5BT. So then BST template will not work.If I add those css and js files related to the BST then it's too much load for the page.B'cos 2 kind of css and js. Any Idea ?

Comment: @Sampath we have used the same template and also bootstrap CSS framework way a lot of projects. We are regularly using the CSS styles that are already defined in Boostrap and there was no problem. And about the template - well I have never used the hero.html source code directly :) so I am not very sure about that.

Bootstrap comes with normalize.css and main.css and the bootstrap.min.css does merge seamlessly merge with the Boostrap framework. So, if you have any specific query, do let me know and I will see if I can help you with that.

Comment: Ok. According to your experience Please tell me how can I use BST Template (hero or what ever ?) with H5BT default template (here I meant when I install or configure H5BT as default project layout).B'cos I am not having any experience about template usage. I need to know the basic set up you're doing when you having such a task (the way of css and js handling) ?